# How to create a flash file using action script

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have few images on to my website. I want to create a flash file where Initially one image would be shown and an audio linked to that imaged should get played. Once the audio is over I want a menu which shows 5 other images. When use clicks on any of the image that image should get displayed and corresponding audio should get played.

I read about creating image gallery using actionscript. But I am not able to understand from where to start and how to solve it.

Any link to a tutorial would be of great help

Comment: Do you have Flash installed (the tool not the plugin)?

Comment: I have installed the flash sdk and am using intellij ide

Comment: Interesting. Because you're inexperienced with ActionScript, I suggest trying out a template from a site like [ActiveDen](http://activeden.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=slideshow) and working from there.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to learn the following skills to do that ..
1. Simple flash animation for navigating through images ..etc
2. XML loading and parsing in Flash
3. Click events listening
4. How to play sound in flash

You can start by learning the above skills to get the job done ..
http://www.gotoandlearn.com/

has great tuts as well.
Good luck :)